# Python does not read updated json data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So, i have a program in python that reads some json data.
I have a c# program to insert data to the json file.
The data is being inserted with success.

My real problem is, let's say i have this data on the json
`[{"a": "b"},{"c": "d"},{"e": "f"}]` by default
When i add more data, the json becomes
`[{"a": "b"},{"c": "d"},{"e": "f"},{"g": "h"}]`
It adds successfully as I said before, but when i run the .py i got all the data as it should be, when i run the same program but as a .exe, I only get the data before the update, so i get this (`[{"a": "b"},{"c": "d"},{"e": "f"}]`)
I'm 100% sure i'm reading from the same file on the 2 programs (c# used to insert, python used to read and work with the data)
I'm reading the data on the python script like this:

```
json_path = f"{os.environ['SYSTEMDRIVE']}\\Program Files\\PFO\\Extensions\\extensions.json"
with open(json_path, "r") as jf:
                #jf.flush()
                d = json.load(jf)
                #Work with data here...
```

I tried out `jf.flush()`, but didn't changed anything.
I have done some research and couldn't find anything that helped me.
I don't know if there's some cache like memory that has to be flushed, or if there's a way to force load the json data every time the program runs.
Does any one know what i'm doing wrong, or the fix for this problem?
If this question doesn't have enough info please tell me and i will edit the question and post it.

Note: The way i'm doing this is:

1. I compile the python file so it becomes a .exe;
2. I run the compiled program to check all the data it's reading;
3. I run the c# program to add data;
4. I re-run the python program after I inserted and closed the c# program so the file is not in use;
5. I verify that the file is updated but the .exe program does not read the updated data;
6. I run the .py in visual code and it reads the new data;

Note 2: To compile the .py to a .exe I open my project folder in visual code, and in console i run this command 
`pyinstaller --onefile -n="PFO" script.py`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `pyinstaller` somehow grabbing the filename as a dependency and including it in your executable?

Comment: I'm not sure but i've done other things with `pyinstaller` and it worked just fine...

Comment: I don't see anything in the code posted here that would affect your ability to *read* the file. `jf.flush()` would write any pending changes by *your* code to disk, not force another writer to flush *their* changes so that you could read them.

Comment: So clearly `jf.flush()` is not the solution, it makes sense because I write to the file from c# and close the file after I wrote the new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after almost 4 hours of debugging i found out the problem was not with the code, but with the location of the folder.
I always run my code editor as administrator, so that's why the .py could read the json data.
But the .exe file was running normally, NOT as an administrator.
To solve this i just basically moved the folder from "C:\Program Files" to "C:Program Files (x86)"

Thanks for those who tried to help, and i hope this is helpful for someone else!